# how to implement background services in react native?

Tags: react-native, mobile-application, background-service

How to implement background service in my app? I want to run the app in the background always without user interaction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.